# How to *ngIf on router link?

Tags: angular

I need to show some content on certain page, in other pages it shouldn't be visible. How do I achieve it ? it doesn't work

`*ngIf="[routerLink]="['/home']"`

Comment: you don't want to show the content of the /home page when you are in a different page ???

Comment: Need more information, your question is not understandable

Comment: I want to show/hide certain elements depending on routerlink

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can inject Router from '@angular/router' and get the current route you're on.

For example:

```
// mycomponent.component.ts
class MyComponent {
    constructor(public router: Router) {

    }
}

// mycomponent.component.html
<div *ngIf="router.url === '/some/route'">

</div>
```

Comment: You are trying to access private property in template view

Comment: Not recommended.

Comment: @Bhavin why is that so?

Comment: @tt9 What if router link contains Id? ex `/link1/link2/{id}'`

Comment: Better save current path in attribute and read it in view than changing to public...

Comment: Make sure the router variable is public in the constructor.

Answer (score 18):

I'm using the other approach.

**template:**

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
   <app-header></app-header>
   <app-banner *ngIf="isHomeRoute()"></app-banner>
</div>
```

**.ts file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  isHomeRoute() {
    return this.router.url === '/';
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it does not expose the private router variable as the accepted answer does.

Comment: this one is better!

Comment: Is there anyway way to check dynamically on route changes, because this only works when the component is loaded (or on browser refresh), doesn't work on route change.

Answer (score 5):

If your routes are well defined you can try this:

```
isTournamentRoute() {
    return this.router.url.includes("/tournament");
}
```

Which is piggybacking off the non accepted answer to add a bit more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach to the others, but I'm only importing  `activatedRoute` to get the exact url param i want (not importing full `router` and grabbing the url string):

*component.ts*

```js
staticParamValue = '123';
paramValue$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(map(paramMap => paramMap.get('paramName')));
  
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

*component.html*

```html
<a *ngIf="(paramValue$ | async) === staticParamValue">
  This link only displays if route param matches the known value
</a>
```

Hope this is useful to someone else too :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, if you have to manage conditional rendering for multiple routes you can try this:

***.html file***

```
<span *ngIf="isPostsOrPostDetails()">WILL BE RENDERED!</span>
```

***.ts file***

```
constructor(private router: Router) {};

isPostsOrPostDetails() {
 const macthOptions = ['/posts', '/post-details'];
 return macthOptions.includes(this.router.url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [router.isActive](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#isActive).

[IsActiveMatchOptions](https://angular.io/api/router/IsActiveMatchOptions) also allow you to specify how exact you want to determine whether the URL is active.

**.html:**

```
<app-component *ngIf="isRouteActive('/home') />
```

**.ts:**

```
private router = inject(Router);

isRouteActive(url: string): boolean {
  const matchOptions: IsActiveMatchOptions = {
    paths: 'subset',
    queryParams: 'subset',
    fragment: 'ignored',
    matrixParams: 'ignored'
  };
  return this.router.isActive(url, matchOptions);
}
```