# Angular 2 Routerlink *ngIf with Param

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have the following routerlink which contains a param:

```
http://localhost:4200/item/1
```

How would I go about doing an *ngIf with a param.... 
I tried the following

```
<div *ngIf="router.url === '/item/:item_id'">
</div>
```

The component which I'm running this *ngIf is a header component which isn't connect to the itemComponent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \*ngIf on router link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139277/how-to-ngif-on-router-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using ActivatedRoute.
Import into your component

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

then get your url value as following..

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
 this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.item_id = +params['item_id'];

});
```

after this you implement your logic for DOM view.